# How to set a fixed relative source point for Spot Removal tool in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

Is there a possibilty to set a fixed relative point where Spot Removal tool in Lightroom should clone from? It seems that Lightroom chooses this point automatically (probably based on similarity of the image areas) and I am almost never satisfied with Lightroom's choice. And sometimes the source point is even beyond the visible area so I need to un-select the tool, zoom out, select the tool, move the source point, un-select the tool,zoom in, select the tool and adjust the source point. I would like to have the source point always set somewhere close to the area to be healed.

I have Lightroom 6.